# Catch next/previous specific attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html is

```
<table>
    <tr><td>w</td><td data-id='6' class='point'>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td data-id='8' class='point'>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Y</td><td data-id='7' class='point'>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Z</td><td data-id='10' class='point'>10</td></tr>
</table>
```

and js is

```
$('.point').click(function(){
    alert($(".point").nextAll().attr('data-id:first'));
});
```

I want to get the value of previous or next `data-id` when I click any point class. How to solve this without using `parent()` and `children()`. My fiddle is [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Iftakharul_alam/Lbpkwn10/) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirement(do not use **"closest"**/parent/children/**"find"**), You can use `.eq()` along with `.index()` to achieve what you need.

Try,

```
var point = $('.point');
point.click(function(){
    alert(point.eq(point.index(this) + 1).attr('data-id'));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0erhb9ch/)

Comment: @prabhu -   Good to see you in SO

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to use `this` to reference the clicked element. Then as the `.point` elements are not siblings `nextAll()` isn't going to work. Instead you need to use `closest()` to find the parent `tr`, go to the next `tr`, then `find()` the `.point` element within that. Try this:

```js
$('.point').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('.point').data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td>w</td><td data-id='6' class='point'>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td><td data-id='8' class='point'>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Y</td><td data-id='7' class='point'>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Z</td><td data-id='10' class='point'>10</td></tr>
</table>
```